# Make JInternal Frame non-moveable

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am making an apllication in **java swing** for practice by using drag and drop components , i am facing a problem, i put inside the JPanel, an JInternal Frame

, **it is moveable**,

> i want to make it **un-moveable**

,which event is used for it? How can i do it ? i search on the internet but unfortunately unable to find the solution for this.

I have found this on internet but i want to do it with the help of event option in swing.

```
     // Make first internal frame unmovable

JInternalFrame[] frames = frame.desktop.getAllFrames();
JInternalFrame f = frames[0];
BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)f.getUI();

Component north = ui.getNorthPane();
MouseMotionListener[] actions =        // there is no option for MouseMotionListener in the event option
(MouseMotionListener[])north.getListeners(MouseMotionListener.class);

for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
north.removeMouseMotionListener( actions[i] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DesktopManager` is resposible for all operation with internal frames. So you can redefine it using the [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to make some of your frames non-movable. Here is non-complete example for you (sorry I havn't tested this code, so I'm not sure whether it works).

```
private static class ProxyDesktopManager implements DesktopManager {

    private final DesktopManager delegate;

    public ProxyDesktopManager(DesktopManager delegate) {
        this.delegate = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate);
    }

    // Check whether frame is moveable
    private boolean checkFrameMovable(JComponent frame) {
        if (frame instanceof JInternalFrame) {
            // TODO check whether the frame if movable

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beginDraggingFrame(JComponent f) {
        if (checkFrameMovable(f)) {
            delegate.beginDraggingFrame(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dragFrame(JComponent f, int newX, int newY) {
        if (checkFrameMovable(f)) {
            delegate.dragFrame(f, newX, newY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDraggingFrame(JComponent f) {
        if (checkFrameMovable(f)) {
            delegate.endDraggingFrame(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void openFrame(JInternalFrame f) {
        delegate.openFrame(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void closeFrame(JInternalFrame f) {
        delegate.closeFrame(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void maximizeFrame(JInternalFrame f) {
        delegate.maximizeFrame(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void resizeFrame(JComponent f, int newX, int newY, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        delegate.resizeFrame(f, newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    // IMPORTANT: simply delegate all another methods like openFrame or 
    // resizeFrame
}
```

Now you can use this proxy class for your JDesktopPane

```
JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
desktop.setDesktopManager(new ProxyDesktopManager(desktop.getDesktopManager()));
```

Comment: can we do it by using some event like mouseClickListener or any other event

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's based on hard coding, i was wondering is there any builtin function available in swing framework, like by using some event ??

Comment: @shaunTait There are no high-level events or listeners available in Swing for this behavior. So you either can deregistrate all mouse listeners (but in this case you also risk to lose all mouse depended behavior of frame like resizing, minimizing, maximizing etc.) or you can use the approach which is suggested by me.

Comment: thanks , it was your above comment which i was trying to find from yesterday, thanks, Sergiy one more favour, it will be great if you recommend me a course of some good instructure or share it's link

Comment: i know this website is not for such questions but it will be great favour  if you recommend me some course for swing by a good instructor or share link will also be fine.

Comment: @shaunTait It's difficult to recomend any book or course which I haven't read/participate. Swing is an outdated technology and only be used now to support some huge legacy B-to-B applications, that cannot be migrated to any modern technology. I would suggest you to learn JavaFx or better any web framework (angular, react or something else).

Comment: angular,react aren't base on PHP?

Comment: @shaunTait No, they are based on Java Script or Typed Script.